# What is the difference between meteor npm and npm when installing packages for a meteor app?

Tags: node.js, meteor

I think that in the `meteor npm` I'm using the "meteor" npm package burried in /home/user/.meteor or smth like that, while `npm` uses the system wide library?

However I'm not sure if it somehow impacts the packages usage in meteor.

Finally this was all trigerred after getting the following error when running:

```
meteor npm install --save material-ui


npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-85-generic
npm ERR! argv "node" "/home/user/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.1.9bkup9++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/npm" "install" "--save" "material-ui"
npm ERR! node v0.10.43
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.22
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package react@15.0.1 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-addons-pure-render-mixin@15.0.1 wants react@^15.0.1
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-dom@15.0.1 wants react@^15.0.1
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-tap-event-plugin@0.2.2 wants react@^0.14.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer material-ui@0.14.4 wants react@^0.14.0

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/user/meteor/app/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38090327/is-npm-install-same-as-meteor-npm-install-in-meteor-1-3

I'd like to confirm the second answer by Tom, as we've run into multiple babel errors due to npm versioning problems.