# Is `npm install` same as `meteor npm install` in Meteor 1.3?

Tags: meteor, npm, npm-install

Going through some meteor libraries, I notice that `npm install` and `meteor npm install` are both used in instructions. I know `Meteor 1.3` introduced support for npm modules, so what is the difference between these two commands?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`meteor npm install` will place the `node_modules` folder at the root of your  project and modify the `package.json` at the root of your meteor project.

While `npm install` will work relative to your current directory.

Source: Experience. I'm not 100% certain, but I have used them both a fair amount.

Answer (score 3):

`meteor npm` will run npm that has been bundled with meteor, this may be a different version than the version of npm installed globally on your system.

You can check versions like `meteor npm -v` and `npm -v`