# What is difference between npm install and meteor npm install

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I am working on Meteor and want to know that what is the difference between

`npm install` and `meteor npm install`.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is \`npm install\` same as \`meteor npm install\` in Meteor 1.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38090327/is-npm-install-same-as-meteor-npm-install-in-meteor-1-3)

Comment: https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-npm-install-vs-npm-install/20495

Answer (score -8, accepted):

This may help you to  understand difference between npm install and meteor npm install

The former is installing npm packages, which will be listed in packages.json and located in the node modules directory and need to be imported into your code.
    The latter is using atmosphere packages which will be listed under .meteor/packages and will be included in your build (no need to import).

Comment: this is incorrect. To use atmosphere packages - ```meteor add ```

Comment: Absolutely but I mean that when we use meteor npm  from atmosphere then they are listed Inside package. Json in .Meteor folder and when we use npm install then they will listed in package.Json and package will listed in node_modules

Comment: @VishnuChauhan - perhaps you should edit your post. Atmosphere packages are handled differently, and the question is about npm packages, not atmosphere packages

Answer (score 13):

According to Meteor Development Group's comments in the official [forum](https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-npm-install-vs-npm-install/20495/3), the difference is as follows;

`meteor npm` calls the bundled `npm` version, so it doesn’t require `npm` to be installed **globally**, That is just a convenience however, so if you do have npm installed using that will work perfectly fine. That being said, it is a good practice to get into always using `meteor npm`, as that way you can make sure you’re using the same `npm` version that has been tested with your current version of `Meteor`.

Answer (score 1):

When using `meteor npm` you can make sure that you are using the same `npm` version that has been tested with your current Meteor's version.

When using `npm install` it just uses the global `npm` on your machine. So i'd advise to use `meteor npm`